# Surface of chest protector is coming off

Tags: equipment

I have an old chest protector from years ago that the surface is peeling  off. It's in good physical shape just the surface is beading off. Is there a way to resurface them, or should I just buy a new one? I just didn't know if there were some sort of spray i could put on it to seal it or not.

Comment: Duct tape, Plastidip, Liquid Vinyl, Liquid Electrical Tape. All of these are things you could try. But since I don't have experience repairing chest protectors, I can't say which is best.

Comment: Personally, given how foam degrades even in the best circumstances, I'd opt for replacing a chest protector from "years ago" that has outer layer compromises.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by beading off:

If you mean that there are holes, it will compromise safety, a toe could get caught in the hole.

If you mean that the coloring is wearing away, it's still sound - but maybe not be for competition.  You might train with it, but a protector that is discolored can be a problem for refereeing.

If you mean that the outer shell is coming away from the undershell, forming bubbles, then you should be fine - although it will not likely last long.

No, there are no resurfacing options that I'm aware of.